# Key sort an array of ad size dimensions? 300x250 should come before 300x1050

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm working with Google AdSense sizes. I have the array below, but I also allow users to enter their own custom ad sizes. I want their ad size to be placed in the correct order in the array. The problem is when the second number in the ad size is over 999, it gets out of order.

```
$adsizes = array(
#   Google Adsense Display and Text Unit Sizes
    '970x90'  => 'Large Leaderboard', 
    '728x90'  => 'Leaderboard',
    '468x60'  => 'Banner ',
    '336x280' => 'Large Rectangle',
    '320x100' => 'Large Mobile Banner',
    '320x50'  => 'Mobile Banner',
    '300x600' => 'Large Skyscraper',
    '300x250' => 'Medium Rectangle',
    '250x250' => 'Square ',
    '234x60'  => 'Half Banner',
    '200x200' => 'Small Square',
    '200x200' => 'Small Square',
    '180x150' => 'Small Rectangle',
    '160x600' => 'Wide Skyscraper',
    '125x125' => 'Button',
    '120x600' => 'Skyscraper',
    '120x240' => 'Vertical Banner',

#   Google Adsense Link Unit Sizes
    '728x15'  => 'Displays 4 links',
    '468x15'  => 'Displays 4 links',
    '200x90'  => 'Displays 3 links',
    '180x90'  => 'Displays 3 links',
    '160x90'  => 'Displays 3 links',
    '120x90'  => 'Displays 3 links',

);
```

For example, if the user enters 300x1050 as their ad size, it would show up below the 300x250 ad here if I just sorted with ksort(). How can I have the size 300x1050 inserted into the correct position which is just above 300x600 in this instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to sort by vertex length:

```
200x99999
300x900
300x1000
400x400
```

In this case you can get away with using [`strnatcmp`](http://php.net/strnatcmp) (and [`uksort`](http://php.net/uksort)) to do a natural order sort (`22` before `150`, `3` before `190`).

```
uksort($adsizes, 'strnatcmp');
```

---

If you want to sort by *surface area*:

```
300x900
400x400
300x1000
200x99999
```

you will need to write your own sort function

Comment: uksort, since OP wants to compare keys, not values.

Comment: uksort looks to be the right one. I need to reverse the order once sorted, but that's easy enough to do with array_reverse(). Thank you!